# OAuth2.0-protected Azure api: Cant get auth token in Postman

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

Im trying to re-create a request from Fiddler in Postman.

I have a web app running locally and Im using fiddler to get the request.

The webapp is calling https://login.microsoftonline.com/[[mytenantname]]/oauth2/token
and gets a auth token back. This works well and I can then call my protected api.

Fiddler:
[image]

But when I try to copy the request in Postman I get that the error message below.

Postman:
[image]

**Scenario 2**

I have also tried calling the web api directly and selecting (in Postman) Authorization->OAuth 2.0 -> [Get Authorization token] ... aso. Here I get a token back but I when using this token I cant make a request (access denied-type of message). If I copy my fiddler-auth token, however, I can get things from my protected api

I have also used tentantId instead of tenantname (orange strikeouts in images)

Comment: I can able to get the error response (400 BAD Request) from the URI which you shared. I tired in the same POSTMAN, also I've not set any Authorization (No Auth). Did check your internet connectivity is working fine?

Comment: Hi Jay. Thanks for your response. The link is not a real one, it includes my Azure tentants  name. Ive updated the post to make it clearer for everyone. Connectivity is not the problem

Comment: 15 chars.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler, being the devil himself, is messing up your request. Disable/remove it and retry your Postman stuff. Happy days.

Try MITM Proxy as Fiddler replacement. It's a beautiful thing and doesn't stab you in the back - https://mitmproxy.org/

Comment: Ok, I *did* answer it myself 20 mins earlier but Ill set yours as the correct answer, because of the tip. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I get that response when Fiddler is running. ("Could not get any response")

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the resource param value with https and retried?
Also just check whether postman is able to connect to internet.